# Python3 creating Tuple works backwards in one case

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

I am creating a graph of minimum heap queues and when I read input like this:

```
3
1 2 7
6 5 4
3 8 9
```

Into this python program:

```
n = int(input())

G = {}

for u in range(n):
    line = input().split()
    minimum_q = []
    for v in range(len(line)):
        if u != v:
            w = int(line[v])
            #obj = {w, (u, v)}
            #heappush(minimum_q, obj)
            heappush(minimum_q, (w, (u, v)))

    G[u] = minimum_q
```

I get some weird behavior. When the obj variable is created to be pushed into the queue, the object looks like this: obj: {(0, 1), 2}
This is anticipated, but when I get to the element "8" in which u = 2, v = 1, w = 8. But the obj looks like this: {8, (2, 1)}

Does anyone have any ideas?

edit: Changed the code to what worked.

Comment: You are creating *sets*, containing a tuple and an integer. Sets have no order.

Comment: Awesome. I'll give it a try. Thanks

Comment: The heap queue has stopped working after the change. Will have to mess around with it some more.